# Line break in my Navigation bar in Chrome but not Firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, navigation, line-breaks

Here is the page in questions: http://www.jacobsievers.com/sample.html

In Firefox and IE, My navigation bar displays correctly, but if you look at it with Chrome there is a line break after 'Gallery'.  I'm wondering if someone can help me figure out what I need to do or change in my code. Something with the nav ul or nav li in my css?

[image: HTML]
<sub>(source: [jacobsievers.com](http://jacobsievers.com/html.jpg))</sub>

[image: CSS]
<sub>(source: [jacobsievers.com](http://jacobsievers.com/css.jpg))</sub>

I don't know how to make those scroll box things that other people put code in so here are some jpgs sorry!  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Copy the code from ST2.  Paste it into the question and highlight it.  Click that little "{}" button in the text editor or do a Ctrl-K to mark it up as code.

Answer (score 1):

```
nav ul {
text-align: center;
width: 700px;
margin: auto;
word-spacing: 50px;
padding: 0;
font-size: 20px;
}
```

Should fix it :)

EDIT:

```
    /************************ =Nav ************************/
 nav ul {
    text-align: center;
    width: 700px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
}
nav li {
    display: inline;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    top:30px;
    margin-left: 100px;
}

nav li:first-child { margin-left: 0px; }

nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(50, 140, 204);
    transition: background-color 2s;
    -moz-transition: background-color 2s;
    /* Firefox 4 */
    -webkit-transition: background-color 2s;
    /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition: background-color 2s;
    /* Opera */
    transition: color 2s;
    -moz-transition: color 2s;
    /* Firefox 4 */
    -webkit-transition: color 2s;
    /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition: color 2s;
    /* Opera */
}
nav a:hover {
    background-color: #E0EEEE;
    color: black;
}
```

jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/andyjh07/cqZTV/

Comment: Thanks Andy, you're right that does fix it, but then I'm not totally happy with the word spacing.  How can I get chrome to be okay with 100px like Firefox is.

Comment: I think it might be better to use margins. Give me a couple of minutes, i'll set up a jsFiddle

Comment: Here you go, should do what you need it to matey :)

Comment: No problem buddy, please select my answer as the correct one (the tick thing)

Comment: I appreciate the upvote whoever did it :) OP Please accept this answer as it's over a year! haha